# How do I disable vim from producing backup files?

Tags: backup

How do I disable vim from producing backup files? Like file~ do not generate. Should I do that by modifying `/etc/vimrc`?

I added `set nobackup` to `/etc/vimrc`, but when I looked at the distributed file system log, the backup file was still generated but it was then deleted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try adding:

`set nobackup nowritebackup`

to your vimrc.

UPDATE with regards to [Jason Lefler's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21714/9333)

If you want to prevent your backup/undo/swap files to be created next to your edited file consider setting directories for them:

```
let &directory = expand('~/.vimdata/swap//')

set backup
let &backupdir = expand('~/.vimdata/backup//')

set undofile
let &undodir = expand('~/.vimdata/undo//')

if !isdirectory(&undodir) | call mkdir(&undodir, "p") | endif
if !isdirectory(&backupdir) | call mkdir(&backupdir, "p") | endif
if !isdirectory(&directory) | call mkdir(&directory, "p") | endif
```

You set `:h directory`, `:h backupdir`, `:h undodir` to whatever you prefer. Note, there is double slash `//` at the end (`~/.vimdata/swap//`) needed to prevent collisions when you edit the same file names in different paths, e.g., there will be files like `C%%Users%%username%%docs%%test.adoc~` and `C%%Users%%username%%docs%%awesome%%test.adoc~` created in `backupdir`.

Then you create those directories if they don't exist. `.vimdata` dir is what I use to have all of them in one place, you can change it of course.

Answer (score 14):

[Maxim's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21709/25466) works for disabling backups entirely, but you can also relocate the backup directory, if you just want to stop cluttering your working directory but want the backup functionality.

`set backupdir=~/.vim/backup`

I also do this for temporary files, as well.

`set directory=~/.vim/tmp`

(These directories may need to already exist.)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Nice first answer—I prefer to preserve these backups too. For my `undodir`, I actually do an `if !isdirectory(expand(&undodir)) | call mkdir(expand(&undodir), "p") | endif` in my vimrc (so you can do this programatically)

Comment: Oo, undodir is new to me.  Gonna look into that one.  More lines for my already-monolithic vimrc file!

Comment: I do the same :)

Comment: Does this solution cause problems if you're editing files in different directories with the same name -- say, `pom.xml` files in various project directories?

Comment: Depends on path of your backupdir. If it ends with double slash then no issues. See corresponding help chapters @jeffB